# Posso realizar uma postagem no meu próprio facebook usando a API?

Tags: php, facebook

Posso realizar uma postagem no meu próprio facebook usando o SDK do face ?
Posso ler meus feed com uma a SDK?
a pergunta é simples, quero contruir minha própria interface para usar meu perfil do facebook da forma que desejo.

Answer (score 4):

Sim podes a documentação de developer do facebook e muito clara quanto a isto.
Para alem de poderes publicar na tua propria pagina tambem podes publicar nas paginas das quais tens permissões administrativas.

Consulta a documentação de developer do facebook em

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0?locale=pt_PT